# EF - Many to many on same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I created a table "Project" and a many to many relationship on it to represent a link between projects

```
CREATE TABLE Project (Id int identity(1, 1) not null, Name varchar(255))
CREATE TABLE ProjectLink(IdProj int not null, IdProj1 int not null)
```

IdProj and IdProj1 are foreign keys referencing Project.Id

When I generate code with EF 4 DbContext Generator I get Project class with two lists like

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public List<Project> LinkedProjects { get; set; }
    public List<Project> LinkedProjectsBack { get; set; }

}
```

So when I do

```
Project A = new Project();
Project B = new Project();
A.LinkedProjects.Add(B);
```

After saving changes when I reload A and B, B is in A.LinkedProjects and A is in B.LinkedProjectsBack

How can I tell EF to generate Project class with only one list?

Comment: While I don't know how to solve your problem, please don't have a variable name that's another variable name with a 1 behind it. It is very confusing to read.

Comment: Not sure you can. The reason this is occurring is that EF can't tell that `IdProj` and `IdProj1` are equivalent. Hence the collection `LinkedProjects` and `LinkedProjects1` aren't the same.